# jquery ajax post error, not sending data to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have no more ideas... maybe someone can help me,

i have this code to get some data in html and send it to php file.

but its not sending.

i controlled every var with alert(), all of them have data, but not sending to php file :/ 
and i also tried send one item only(maybe one does not work), but still nothing and anyway it does not seem logical to, because i tested every var and all of them have correct data

```
<?php $kuupaev = date('Y-m-d');  ?>
     <script>
    //This handles the queues    
    (function($) {

      var ajaxQueue = $({});

      $.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) {

        var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;

        ajaxQueue.queue(function(next) {

          ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
            if (oldComplete) oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);

            next();
          };

          $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
        });
      };

    })(jQuery); 

    $('.programmeheading').eq(0).remove(); 
    $('.programmeheading').eq(1).remove(); 
     var kordame = $(".season").length;   
     var viimane = <?php echo $_GET['kanal']; ?>; 
     var kanaliid = <?php echo $_GET['kanal']; ?>; 
     var total = kordame;
     var loeme = 0;  
     var kavaautor = 'guide';          

     for(var index = 0; index < kordame; index++)
      {                   

       var kuupaev = '<?php echo $kuupaev; ?>';
        var kanal = '<?php echo $kuva_kanal['nimi']; ?>';  
        var pealkiri = $('a span.programmeheading').eq(index).text(); 
        var kell = $('.season').eq(index).text(); 
        var jargmine = $('.season').eq(index+1).text(); 
        //var pilt = $(".schedTv .title img").eq(index).attr("alt");
        var sisu = $("a span.programmetext").eq(index).text();         

       $.ajaxQueue({    
            url: 'salvesta_kanalid.php', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {kuupaev:kuupaev,kanal:kanal,kell:kell,pealkiri:pealkiri,
                   sisu:sisu,kanaliid:kanaliid,jargmine:jargmine,
                   kavaautor:kavaautor},
            success: function(data) {
             loeme++;
                $('.status').html(data); 
                if(total == loeme) { alert('success')   } 
            }
        });   

      }     
     </script>
```

bigg thanks

Comment: you have any reason to use ajaxQueue? otherwise try using $.post

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: yes, i have big reason. i collecting data from html and saving all data to mysql. but if i used just $.post , then that not saved correct to mysql. but with ajaxQueue saving correct. sorry, bad english...

Comment: amm, can you make it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: everything working now.. the page where i crab html, had some js code what bloked my code to working correctly, now everything ok :)